# C# html in xaml

Tags: c#, html, xaml, input

I have the following problem:

So I have an HTML string with inputfields etc... And I have a usercontrol in xaml where I want to show this html. but when there's an input field there shoould be the possibility to change the text in the inputfield. And everything should be editable.

Comment: What's the problem?  You need a XAML-based HTML editor?

Comment: What is the problem? You've only told us what you have and what you want.

Comment: It's more like a question how I should do this. 
@Kieren: Yes

Answer (score 1):

You can do Rich Text editing in WPF, and you can convert the results to/from XAML, HTML, ..

Some resources to get you started:

http://www.developerfusion.com/community/blog-entry/8393336/bindable-wpf-richtext-editor-with-xamlhtml-convertor/

http://www.silverlightshow.net/news/Bindable-WPF-RichText-Editor-with-XAML-HTML-Convertor-.aspx

Comment: And do you think it is suitable for the following task:

We have to make an appliation for teachers, so people who don't know much about pc's so that they can make their own Questions On the pc. so they have to edit the text of the question, So the tags should dissappear